# I keep receiving Error 1304: Error writing file. What to do?

Tags: installation

I am trying to install Office 16, however whenever I try to install it I keep receiving this error:

[image: Error 1304. Error writing to file. Verify that you have access to that directory]

I tried installing LibreText and the same error occurred. My laptop specs are as below:

Windows 10 32-bit
4GB Ram

What to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Turn off Anti-Virus
(consider turning UAC off, at least whilst you install)
Right-click the MSI file & select "Run as Administrator"
Right click on the MSI file, select Properties and see if there is an option to unblock file (this sometimes can happen when copying files around).
Weird fix was to create a 2nd Administrator & use that as the user when 'run as admin'.
An even more thorough right-click advice on install file that worked:
a) click on Compatibility Tab
b) at bottom is "Privilege Level"
c) Check the box that says "Run this program as an administrator." 
d) Below that, check the box that says Compatibility for all users
e) check the run as administrator box also